# Adding a debug point as soon as an error appears MATLAB

Tags: matlab, debugging

this might be silly, Is there any way to automatically place a debug point when an error pops up in MATLAB

Error popping is done manually by

`msg = 'Error has occurred'`

`error(msg)`

What I need is, to automatically put a debug (not by manual intervention) after popping this error.

Comment: Do you want the program to pause in debug mode when any error occurs? Or do you want to set a debug breakpoint when an error occurs, so that _next time_ it will pause there?

Comment: debug breakpoint at the line of error or before the line of error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [dbstop](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dbstop.html#d120e258414) with a condition:

```
dbstop if error
```

> MATLAB pauses at any line in any file when the specified condition
>   occurs.